# how to create a popup window by ONLY using JavaScript in outlook add-in

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

in this code below: I need to create a popup window under "setSubject". i.e when I compose a message I need to see a popup window. So the popup window code should be written under function setSubject(event) {

```
function onMessageComposeHandler(event) {
setSubject(event);
}
function onAppointmentComposeHandler(event) {
setSubject(event);
}
function setSubject(event) {
 Office.context.mailbox.item.subject.setAsync(
    "Set by an event-based add-in!",
    {
        "asyncContext": event
    },
    function (asyncResult) {
        // Handle success or error.
        if (asyncResult.status !== 
        Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            console.error("Failed to set subject: " + 
        JSON.stringify(asyncResult.error));
        }

        // Call event.completed() after all work is done.
        asyncResult.asyncContext.completed();
    });
}
```

Comment: What stops you from adding a popup? Where is the relation to Outlook?

Comment: onMessageComposeHandler is an event in outlook add-in. Check this out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch

Comment: Please share what you tried so far

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the code inside setSubject is to add an automatic subject when we compose a new message in outlook. Similarly, I need an automatic popup modal instead of the automatic subject.

Comment: To ensure a smooth user experience, for LaunchEvent add-ins currently the APIs which invoke a UI element like a popup window are not supported.Please submit a feature request if needed  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform .and we will let update if this changes in the future.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure a smooth user experience, for LaunchEvent add-ins currently the APIs which invoke a UI element like a popup window are not supported.Please submit a feature request if needed  [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) and we will let update if this changes in the future.